# How to get user's feed from Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS app that has a feed system basically like Facebook (With Firebase as server) and I'm trying to get the **latest** `Posts` from all the people that the user is following, but I can't find a way to loop through all data. Can I get a hand?

So this is more or less how my database is:

```
{
  "Posts" : {
    "Zlv1rX3p74R4G8DUvvBOcCiThcx1" : {
      "-KacGJ-ps8FgCYvSag-D" : {
        "latitud" : "37.33233141",
        "longitud" : "-122.0312186",
        "text" : "Party at my house",
        "timestamp" : "1484586828.01879",
        "ubicacionN" : "Apple Inc."
      }
    }
  },
  "following" : {
    "Zlv1rX3p74R4G8DUvvBOcCiThcx1" : {
      "Bdxaooy1HieFajZfZL8OeDFS1Q73" : {
        "Uid" : "Bdxaooy1HieFajZfZL8OeDFS1Q73",
        "handle" : "dnla",
        "name" : "Daniela",
        "profile_pic" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got the posts in one part and the list of following in another part (I'll add a complete pic of my DB at the end)

I'm not really familiar with `NSDictionary` so that's why I'm running into troubles, so I started doing this:

```
    self.databaseRef.child("following").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        //Getting the list of following
        let snapshot = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        self.following.append(snapshot)

    }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    for item in self.following  {
Some code to get every user that the main user is following latests posts

    }
```

but I'm hitting my head right now, some help please.

Picture explanation: `Jalas` = `Posts`

[image: Data Base Pic]

[image: Data Base Pic]

Comment: To confirm, you are already getting the Posts you want, but you want the latest?

Comment: No @AubtinSamai, i'm getting only the users posts not the posts from the people the user is following

Comment: You could try to save all the posts based on user UID, then just retrieve them using a loop based on UID through the 'Posts' node. You'd have to try this and see if it is efficient though, it might not be... The more people the user is following, the slower it would get. Use Query and load as little as you can load initially from each post group from the users.